# Do we need to set the index on the collection for the order by fields also?

Tags: mongodb

I have read that removing unncecessary  Index can improve mongodb's performance a lot .
I am working on a Application which is dependent on mongodb very heavily .
I have seen that some of the queries inside the application is querying the data using order by on two attributes of a document .

My question is

**Do we need to set the index on the collection for the order by fields also?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think so. Refer: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes/
It says:

> In MongoDB sort operations that sort documents based on an indexed
>   field provide the greatest performance. Indexes in MongoDB, as in
>   other databases, have an order: as a result, using an index to access
>   documents returns in the same order as the index.